# Partially overwriting the contents of a file descriptor

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to create a file, and later partially overwrite the contents. The following program captures the gist of what I am trying to do

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
int main() {

            string tmpFilePath = "/tmp/myfile.XXXXXX";
            int fd = mkstemp(&(tmpFilePath[0]));
            string s1 = "Hello World";
            FILE *fp = fdopen(dup(fd), "a");
            fwrite(s1.c_str(), s1.size(), 1, fp);
            fclose(fp);
            fp = fdopen(dup(fd), "r+");
            string s2 = "HELLO";
            fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(s2.c_str(), s2.size(), 1, fp);
            fclose(fp);
            rename(tmpFilePath.c_str(), "/tmp/myfile");
}
```

The intention is to create a file that has the contents "HELLO World". This works fine on a Mac, but on a Virtualbox VM running Linux, the file contents end up as "Hello WorldHELLO". Am I doing something that causes undefined behavior? What would be the right way to go about overwriting the file partially?

Comment: FWIW I voted to re-open this, just out of principle. Closing it gives the impression that it's a bad question, but it seems perfectly reasonable to me. It even includes a complete, runnable example. I don't think there's anything more that can be said by way of answering, to be honest, but it's not a defective question.

Comment: I removed the [tag:c] tag. Don't spam your questions with unrelated tags - and this is not a C program. Oh, and I agree and voted to reopen it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an (externally) undocumented feature of glibc.

The source code of `fdopen` says:

```
/* The May 93 draft of P1003.4/D14.1 (redesignated as 1003.1b)
   [System Application Program Interface (API) Amendment 1:
   Realtime Extensions], Rationale B.8.3.3
   Open a Stream on a File Descriptor says:

   Although not explicitly required by POSIX.1, a good
   implementation of append ("a") mode would cause the
   O_APPEND flag to be set.

   (Historical implementations [such as Solaris2] do a one-time
   seek in fdopen.)

   However, we do not turn O_APPEND off if the mode is "w" (even
   though that would seem consistent) because that would be more
   likely to break historical programs.
   */
```

So the first `fdopen` (with the "a" mode) sets the `O_APPEND` flag in the underlying *file description*, and the second `fdopen` does not unset it so it continues to be in effect.

Methods of dealing with the problem are many, including:

1. Do not use `dup`, open the file separately, thus creating a separate file description (`dup`ed descriptors share the same underlying file description)
2. Do not use `"a"`, seek to the end and write instead
3. Use `fcntl` to turn off `O_APPEND` manually

Comment: Unix is such a clusterf***. Piles upon piles of hacky workarounds for previous braindamage and breakage breaking over and over.

Comment: Using fcntl to turn off the APPEND flag worked. Thanks so much!

Comment: I could not open the file in a different mode to start with, because that was third party code.

Answer (score 2):

The undefined behaviour here, I think, is that `fdopen()` can't be used with arbitrary behaviour flags, as `fopen()` can. The behaviour flags must match the original open mode of the file descriptor (the various `O_XXX` flags to `open()`).

All the file descriptors in the OP begin with a call to `mkstemp()`, which returns a file open for read and write, with initial position zero. Consequently, the only valid behaviour flags for `fdopen()` are `r+` or `w+`. In order for `a` to be valid, the file would originally have to be opened with `O_APPEND`, which it wasn't.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any references for this behavior?

Comment: `man fdopen`: "The  mode  of the stream (one of the values "r", "r+", "w", "w+", "a", "a+") must be compatible with the mode of the file  descriptor. "

Comment: The actual POSIX standard says "The application shall ensure that the mode of the stream as expressed by the mode argument is allowed by the file access mode of the open file description to which fildes refers". It isn't clear why "a" wouldn't be allowed by "w". The standard also says "Although not explicitly required by this volume of POSIX.1-2017, a good implementation of append (a) mode would cause the O_APPEND flag to be set" so it doesn't seem to consider this combination invalid.

Comment: I've not read the POSIX specification and won't be doing so until it is the last book left unburned. However, I've always read the second argument of `fdopen()` as expressing not a wish, but a necessity. That is, I've always assumed, rightly or wrongly, that I had to set an open mode that matched the existing file descriptor, because the implementation could not work it out. I don't believe Linux exposes a way to change the O_XXX mode of an existing file descriptor, or even to find out what the existing mode is. I could be wrong, of course.

Comment: For the last part, you can actually use fcntl for getting and setting O_XXXX flags on the open fd (I ended up doing that).

Comment: @SPMP -- OK; thanks.. It remains unclear to me whether the documented behaviour of `fdstat()` on Linux is properly compliant with POSIX, or not, to be honest. Frankly, I've generally avoided using it.